# How are natural language generation algorithms given a target

Tags: nlp, nlg

I've started learning about NLP and NLG and I'm fascinated! I've been blown away by the things I've seen from NLP; but I have a few questions about NLG. All my questions boil down to this:

Given a network or Markov chain how does one specify what you want the system to talk about?

To explain this a little; if I ask my 5 year old nephew to tell me something he'll talk about his toys, or what's on TV etc. whatever he decides - but I can also ask him to talk to me about something specific eg. *tell me about dinosaurs*, then he'll give me a few sentences about his favourite dino. How does one specify they want their NLG system to talk about dinosaurs specifically once you've fed the system the whole of Wikipedia?

Answer (score 1):

Most natural language generation (NLG) systems have the option to input words as a prompt to seed the system.